# How do I link AccountTeamMembers to Contact objects?

Tags: account, query, contact, roles, account-teams

I’m using SalesForce v 33.0 and I am trying to write a single query that, given a number of account ids, can identify the team members (their first name, last name, and email) whose roles are designated as “Manager”.  I would like to figure out with which accounts these team members are associated.  I have this

```
Select Id, AccountId From AccountTeamMember WHERE TeamMemberRole = 'Manager' and AccountId in ('001F000001INbk8', '001F000001INbk7', ...)
```

but I am stuck because I don’t know how to associate the AccountTeamMemember object back to a Contact object where the first name, last name, and email data live.

I will eventually use the results of this query with the Java API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AccountTeamMembers are related to User objects, not contacts. In SOQL you can access lookup relationships via dot-nation as fields to return in your statement. For your requirements you can do this like:

```
Select Id, AccountId, User.FirstName, User.LastName, User.Email From AccountTeamMember
WHERE TeamMemberRole = 'Implementation Manager' 
and AccountId in ('001F000001INbk8', '001F000001INbk7', ...)
```